# Why are files I create on a mounted drive owned by a different user?

Tags: samba

My main user is UID=1001, but when I create files on a mounted drive, they end up with ownership of UID-1000...  Other users on this machine don't have the issue.

How might I fix this?

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  What does this have to do with samba?  Is this a locally mounted drive or network share?  How is it being mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably part of the mount command you used or the fstab entry you created for that particular mount.

If you followed a [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) you may have created a line in file `/etc/fstab` that looks like:

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Replace `uid=1000` with `uid=1001` and you will be fine.

**Edit**

If you have another user with UID 1000 then he/she will end up having exactly the same problem. The way around that is not to use /etc/fstab but both of you have an autostart script that does:

```
mount -t cifs //servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare-userX -o guest,uid=100X,iocharset=utf8
```

You will need to replace `userX` and `100X` with the correct values, create directories `/media/windowsshare-userX` and set the owher of these directories to be the respective user.

Comment: That is so unbelievably simple that I am upset that I didn't try it.  Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you check what I wrote after **Edit** and not create a problem for an eventual other user of the same machine.